# How i can doing for introducing a list objects from database's values in a function of javascript for draw points in map openlayer?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, openlayers-3

my problem is that i can draw a point or points if this is differents variables in a map in javascript, but when i use a {{mission_template}} that is a list of objects from database i cant iterate in this !!...

my function in javascript is this :

```
  function AddMakers(){
     for (var i=0; i<50; i++){
        var x={{mission_template.GPSlongitude}};
        var y={{mission_template.GPSlatitude}};
        var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([x,y], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
       name: 'Marker ' + i
        });
        markers[i]= [x,y];
        vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
      }
  }
 .... rest scripts....
```

And use Django and Python for programming.
I can iterating in this only in my template, but cant use that data for iterate for using in map .
i Use :

```
 {% for mission_template  in mission_template %}
  ...rows and cols for html...
  {{mission_template.GPSlongitude}}
  {{mission_template.GPSlongitude}}
 {%endfor%}
```

All the information is in this variable.

I want iterate in javascript in this variable {{mission_template}}
 Thanks!!

Regards ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the javascript list using template loop and then iterate over this list using the javascript loop:

```
var points = [
    {% for mt in mission_template %}
       [{{ mt.GPSlongitude }}, {{ mt.GPSlatitude }}]
       {% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
];

for (var i = 0, len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
    var x = points[i][0];
    var y = points[i][1];
    ...
}
```

Comment: I solve the problem yet, but I proving your method and is better that the my code.